# is there any conditions for iphone enterprise certificate

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution, enterprise

hello all
I developed an enterprise iphone app

1. small company can use enterprise i.e in-house distribution say approx 200 employees and
2. is it possible for our customer to download iphone app without app store

thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the app store?

Comment: ya ,because each customer have to go to app store and create account for that and download, instead if just we can provide a link to them and they will click and download app..i dont know its possible or not

Comment: Registering through the app store would be much easier for both you and the user rather than them having to you a UDID and then you having to generate a new certificate with their UDID.

Comment: thats true, also may be if apple rejects app then again there is a problem, because u never know why they reject so for more secure reasons i am searching any possibility with $299 certificate for both employee and customers

Comment: if there is possibility then many people can use that else we  have to go with $99 program

Answer (score 1):

Neither an Enterprise iOS program enrollment (which may only require a Dunn & Bradstreet number), nor a standard iOS Developer company enrollment, would allow customers (other than up to 100 for time-limited Ad Hoc test distribution) to download apps outside Apple's App store.

The Enterprise program only allows distribution to employees (as many as the company has).  For over 100 customers (as opposed to employees), a company would have to submit the app to Apple for App store distribution.

Comment: is there any ways to distribute app to customer without app store

Comment: It is possible. See my comment to Twelve47's answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.The company should have atleast
    500 employees to be eligible for an
    enterprise license.

2) With
    enterprise license you can't
    distribute your app through
    appstore, only in-house(distribution
    inside the organization is allowed).

Comment: I think Apple has recently lifted the 500 employees restriction. You can refer this link http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: Yes..the comment above your comment is mine too!!

Comment: @Vin,@Twelve47,ok that means small company can also register for $299 enterprise but the same in-house app is for customer so for customers company  have to purchase other $99 certificate for distribution to their customers or their is any other way?

Comment: You need to have a standard license if you have to distribute through app store.

Comment: I want to distribute to customer without app store is there any ways to do it ?

Comment: There are two ways to do it through enterprise license: 1) Add your client's device to the provisioning portal and build your app using ad-hoc provisioning profile. 2) Create an in-house distribution profile to deploy your app to devices which are not added into portal.

Answer (score 0):

You need the UDID of each device you want to install on. Then you don't have to go through the app store. However if you are doing this for the public instead of employees you are probably breaking apple's terms.

To become an enterprise developer you need a  Dun & Bradstreet number.  Apple also used to require your company had a least 500 staff, I believe they've dropped that requirement now.

Comment: ya, thats true but you can not ask to each customer the UDID

Comment: That's only the way (short of jailbreaking every device).  There are ways to make it easier to get this information like this app http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ad-hoc-helper/id285691333?mt=8  or if they are company deployed devices setup with iPhone Configuration Utility then you can export the list.

Comment: Actually it's possible without jail breaking the device through  in-house distribution certificate(Available for enterprise license). Although it is supposed to be used for the devices of employees only. Deploying an app signed with in-house profile, on the device of someone out of the organization would be a license violation. But it is possible.

Comment: @Vin I thought in-house distribution required UDIDs still... Does an app signed with a enterprise distribution certificate work on any device?

Comment: Apps signed with ad-hoc profile can only be installed on devices added on the provisioning portal. Those signed with in-house can be installed on any iOS device. Although distributing apps this way to consumers or any one outside the organization is a license voilation.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of the question about installing without the app store - see this link [about installing apps wirelessly](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) (search for the word 'wireless' on the page). It *almost* feels like installing things from the app store - there is one more dialog that occurs the first time you launch the app asking if you want to accept it.

But legally you can only distribute to employees of your enterprise.